# How to dynamically change width of Div1 inside a scrollable Div2 to Div2's width

Tags: html, css

How to dynamically change width of Div1 inside a scrollable Div2 to Div2's width.
Check this Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xdKrF/34/
You will see that the green background stops at 1 point(at default width size).
I would like to make the div with the green background expand to the whole scrollable div.

Important requirement, TEXT must never be altered and must stay in 1 line.

Does anyone have a simple solution to this?
Complex/hacky solution I can think of is scrollable will have 1000% width and when its not scrollable it would be default/100%. Using @media.

HTML

```
<div id="container" style="overflow:auto">
<div id="content">
    Well hello
</div>
<p>TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</p>
```

CSS

```
#content{
white-space:nowrap;
background:green;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have found a solution.

Wrap a container and apply `float:left;` for it.

http://jsfiddle.net/2ugbkb6r/

Comment: I changed float:left with display:inline-block because somehow other elements outside the div gets the background??? Will test why to contribute to the community when I'm free.

Comment: @JaredT Because of the `float:left;` You may add a div with `clear:both` to solve this. Like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/t317hnLn/

Answer (score 2):

May be there is will be better answer, but it's working. Just add `display:table;` to `#container` http://jsfiddle.net/xdKrF/36/

Comment: nice solution greate.

Comment: You will add display:table; to parent. In my variant it is #container. In yours there is 2 parents: #container and #container1 .Just add display:table; to #container1

Comment: It gets scrolled with the rest of the elements... The scrolling should only happen within the div with the green background and TEXT spam.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code: (
[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/xdKrF/35/))

```css
#content{
    white-space:nowrap;
    background:green;
}
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;    
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        Well hello
    </div>
    <p>
        TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
    </p>  
</div>
```

Comment: This would be the solution to the problem, if however you want to expand the background-color of the 1st div instead of fitting the text into the screen, just use fixed lenghts for both and overflow:hidden to delete extra TEXT

Comment: Extra texts are important! and the text needs to be in 1 row.